# Consolidate htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have rules for forcing www and suppressing php extensions. How can I consolidate them into one rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot combine them into 1 rules since one rule is external redirect and 2nd in doing rewrite internal only.

But you can correct the 2nd rule a bit:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```